# Feeding Naive Bayes classification model background statistics prior to fitting

Tags: classification, natural-language, naive-bayes

I have a few thousand tagged documents that I use to train a Naive Bayes text classifier (using `sklearn` in this case). In addition to the tagged documents, I have about 100k untagged documents.

The accuracy is OK (~78%), but the model is overfitting the training data. I want to try to weigh the tfidf features after their frequency in the *whole corpus* before I feed the feature vector to the model. I'm sure there is a name for this procedure but I don't know what it is.

For instance, a specific word may be very rare in the training data but common in the untagged dataset. I want to take statistics such as that into account. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Transformed Weight Complement Naive Bayes.

https://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf

Comment: @miroli There is an implementation in python here https://github.com/Nanofication/TWC-Naive-Bayes

Comment: Thanks! I saw that it's currently being implemented in sklearn as well. Will try them both out. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.ComplementNB.html